# How do you do loops for a text based rpg on python?

Tags: python, loops

Im creating a text-based rpg and i need to figure out how to do loops for it so i can go back to the main story tile they progress. I need to loop Map back to the options part.

```
story = input("What do you do? your choices -> Map, Travel, Exit")
if story == "Exit":
    print("you left the game, goodbye" + " " + Name + "!")
    import sys
    sys.exit()
if story == "Map":
    print("Your map shows an abandoned house, Lake, Lab, and abandon asylum.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, perhaps something like this?

```
while True:
    story = input("What do you do? your choices -> Map, Travel, Exit")
    if story == "Exit":
        print("you left the game, goodbye" + " " + Name + "!")
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    if story == "Map":
        print("Your map shows an abandoned house, Lake, Lab, and abandon asylum.")
```

I would personally make a couple alterations though:

```
import sys

while True:
    story = input("What do you do? your choices are: Map, Travel, Exit").lower()
    if story == "exit":
        print("you left the game, goodbye {}!".format(Name))
        sys.exit()
    elif story == "map":
        print("Your map shows an abandoned house, lake, lab, and abandoned asylum.")
```

- Import sys at the beginning
- Make sure capitals don't matter in the input (saving frustrating gaming experience)
- Fixed typos in the last print statement
- You may want to change input to something else so it always works, no matter if you use python 2 or 3